# In a sequence in a normed space are the coefficientes bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $V$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $B \subset V$ be a infinite subset of $V$ linearly independents

Let $U=\operatorname{span}(B)$ be the finite linear span of $B$ such that
$$
\exists b_0 \in B: b_0 \in \overline{\operatorname{span}(B \setminus \{b_0\} )}
$$
and 
$$
\forall b \in (B \setminus \{b_0\}): b \notin \overline{\operatorname{span}(B \setminus \{b\} )}
$$
Let $\{u_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in U$ be a sequence of $U$ such that
$$
u_n=\sum_j
a_{n,j}b_{n,j}
$$
where $a_{n,j} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $b_{n,j} \in B$
and moreover
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n =b \in (B \setminus \{b_0\})
$$

My question is if $|a_{m,j}|$ is bounded, that is $\exists M>0 : \forall m,j |a_{m,j}| < M$

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: @Crostul you are right but now i edited and corrected

Comment: Not necessarily, consider for example in $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ $b_0=  e_0$, $b_n= \frac1n e_0 +\frac1{n^2} e_n$ for $n>0$. This satisfies your conditions and $a_{n,j} = \delta_{n,j} \sqrt n$ is not bounded with $u_n = \frac1{\sqrt n} e_0 + \frac1{n^{3/2}} e_n\to0$. If you demand $\|b_n\|=1$ this example dies and it may be true.

Comment: @s.harp Your $u_n$ converges to $0$, not to an element of $B \setminus \{b_0\}$. You could correct it by adding a constant sequence $e_1$ to $u_n$.

Comment: @mechanodroid indeed, I had missed that restriction. I assume you mean adding $b_1$, then since $u_n\to 0$ one has $\tilde u_n:=u_n+b_1\to b_1$ where the $\tilde a_{n,j}$ are still unbounded.

Comment: @s.harp i beg your pardon, i'm not expert, could you tell me the conditions of $B$ for bounded coefficient of sequences convergent to just one point (not all sequence) of $span(B)$. thanks so much

Comment: @MateyMath do you mean what conditions on $B$ are necessary so that any convergent bounded coefficient sequence converges to a point in span(B)? With $B$ being countable and linearly independent I think you should be able to construct uncountably many linearly independent vectors of the form:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^n \min\left(1,\frac1{\|b_n\|}\right) b_n\qquad \lambda\in (0,1)$$
these are all limits of bounded coefficient series, but you have way more of them than you can have simultaneously linear independent vectors in $\text{span}(B)$. So $B$ has to be uncountable at least.

Comment: ok @s.harp thanks for your assistence, i'll try to find it... thanks again